# Showing HighCharts in A JQuery Mobile application

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, highcharts

I have the following piece of code of the main page of a JQuery Mobile application. It is basically a simple main page with a button that redirects to another page ('chart 1') which contains 2 tab bars in the footer: one for itself ('chart1') and the other for another page ('chart2'). I would like to add in the content section of these two pages some chart from the HighCharts library when these pages are loaded. I have tried several methods (live, bind etc..) but nothing seems to work. The only way to show the charts is with the ready method (see below). My question is: is there a method that displays the charts in the specific area of the page when a button is clicked?

Method to load the charts:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'containerYear',
        type: 'column',
        margin: [ 50, 50, 100, 80]
    },...and so on
});
```

Main page code:

```
 <div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="main-page">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>Data</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
            <li data-role="list-divider">Data</li>
            <li><a href="#chart1" id="btn1" data-transition="slide">Graphs</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h4>CTK</h4>
    </div>
</div>

 <div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="chart1">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
       <a href="#main-page" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse">Back</a>
        <h1>Car Crashes</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="containerYear"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#chart1" data-role="tab" class="ui-btn-active">Chart 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#chart2" data-role="tab" >Chart 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>


<div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="chart2">
     <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <a href="#main-page" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse">Back</a>
        <h1>Car Crashes</h1>
     </div>
     <div data-role="content">
         <div id="containerMonth"></div>
     </div>
     <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#chart1" data-role="tab">Chart 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#chart2" data-role="tab" class="ui-btn-active">Chart 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

jQuery Mobile is unique when used wihh other js drawing frameworks. They can only be used with a pageshow event.

One more thing, remember to initialize HighCharts after jQuery Mobile has been initialized.

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/Eg9Xz/

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>    
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="index">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <h3>
                First Page
            </h3>
            <a href="#second" class="ui-btn-right">Next</a>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
        </div>

        <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

        </div>
    </div>             
</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript :**

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#index', function(){    
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'line',
                marginRight: 130,
                marginBottom: 25
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
                x: -20 //center
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
                x: -20
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                    'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Temperature (°C)'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                        return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                        this.x +': '+ this.y +'°C';
                }
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: -10,
                y: 100,
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Tokyo',
                data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
            }, {
                name: 'New York',
                data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
            }, {
                name: 'Berlin',
                data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
            }, {
                name: 'London',
                data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
            }]
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: If I dont include 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
the desired chart is not shown, however if i include it, the output is shown(I am debugging on pc browser). So does that mean that when i will deploy it on mobile or tablet, it wont work????